# excel data validation not working after copy paste

Tags: java, excel, poi-hssf, hssf

I am using the below code to restrict the user from giving an input less than 10 characters, but when I copy and paste the data into the cell it is overriding the validation. How do I solve this?

```
cell = row.createCell(colIndex++);
CellRangeAddressList cellRangeAddressListCur1 = new CellRangeAddressList();
cellRangeAddressListCur1.addCellRangeAddress(cell.getRowIndex(), cell.getColumnIndex(), cell.getRowIndex(), cell.getColumnIndex());
DVConstraint dvConstraint = DVConstraint.createNumericConstraint(DVConstraint.ValidationType.TEXT_LENGTH, OperatorType.LESS_THAN, "10", null); 
HSSFDataValidation xssfDataValidation = new HSSFDataValidation(cellRangeAddressListCur1, dvConstraint);
xssfDataValidation.setErrorStyle(HSSFDataValidation.ErrorStyle.STOP); 
xssfDataValidation.createErrorBox("Error Message", "Please enter less than 10 characters"); 
xssfDataValidation.setSuppressDropDownArrow(false); 
sheet.addValidationData(xssfDataValidation); 
cell.setCellStyle(textCellStyle);
```

Comment: Can anyone please post a solution for this?I tried several forums including com4j and JACOB  but none works! We are generating a custom excel and to build MACRO dynamically at runtime.

Comment: Are solutions possible in C#?

Comment: HI all,Finally found solution to this problem.We did not create a macro dynamically.We created an excel with below macro and loaded it everytime.